# Remove WhiteSpace From MultiPicklist Value

Tags: configuration

We have a Multipicklist Name Planning LOB on Qute Line Editor where a white space value is coming up as default along with other values, can anyone please advise how can we remove the white space from multipicklist values. 
[image]

Comment: By any chance does the record already have a value for that field where the value = blank string (rather than null)?